# htaccess to catch all image requests and redirect to proper folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

how do i redirect all image requests to a specific folder, since my site has some mod rewriting for nicer urls, sometimes when an image is not found it is handled by the main access route, which is wrong, since htaccess should redirect properly.

i already got:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^$                        index.php  [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}       !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}       !-d

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?([^/]*)/?/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)$ index.php?account=$1&task=$2&object_id=$3&app_type=$4
```

all image requests should be routed to /public/images/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
  RewriteRule (.*)\.(gif|jpg|png)$ /public/images/$1.$2 [R,L]
```

Comment: hey there, looks promising, but i need to redirect to the name of the file in public/images, so it must be something that also gets the img filename and redirect to /public/images/filename.gif

Comment: hey, i've got: RewriteRule (.*)\.(gif|jpg|png)$ /public/images/$1 [R,L], now i need to add the extension only, help plis.

Comment: easiest way i can think of for extensions: break up rules in three , on for each extension. e.g for gif RewriteRule (.*)\.gif$ /public/images/$1.gif [R,L].

Comment: ah never mind . Dont split the rules , rather see my edited answer, we have the extesion captured in $2 :). Hope this helps